# Simplifying sums that contain factorials and have an index that doesn't start at 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I'm trying to simplify the following sum:

$P(a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n-a}}{(n-a)!}$

I'm tempted to turn this into some sort of exponential function because it closely ressembles the Maclaurin series $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$. Below is my attempt at this:

let $N=n-a$ so index now starts at $N=a$

$P(a)=\sum_{N=a}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^N}{N!}$

So now I have succeeded in making a function that is of the same form. Unfortunately, I don't really know what to do about the sum starting at N=a. Rewriting, I get:

$P(a)=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^N}{N!}-\sum_{N=0}^a\dfrac{x^N}{N!}$

Now I definitely can write the first term as an exponential yaaay! But I'm still left with a finite sum that I have to subtract. So I guess what I'm really asking is what do I do about the second term?

Edit: It seems my first equation is incorrect. Here is the context surrounding my question:

[image: Context surrounding my original question]

Note: The variables were relabeled in my original question and constants factors were pulled out to make things a little easier on the eye.
I'm currently on part b). Subbing the given $P(n|N)$ and $P(N)$ expressions into P(n), I find that a negative factorial is inevitable but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Is $a$ meant to be a positive whole number? Because otherwise using it as an index doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you sure this is the sum you’re trying to simplify? (I’m talking about the first equation in your answer) Oftentimes, you actually start the sum from index $a$. This is because such sums often arise from differentiating a series, and differentiating polynomials of small degree many times will cause them to be zero, hence the first few terms in the series will be zero.

Comment: Like Benjamin I think you should double-check whether the sum really starts at $0$ or at $a$. As written you need to compute negative factorials and these are undefined (even using the Gamma function).

Comment: @BenjaminWang I'm fairly certain I have the right equation but I'll double check. Why, is that equation impossible to simplify in an elegant way?

Comment: @mwalth yes, $a$ is a positive whole number. Its supposed to represent a detected particle and $n$ is supposed to represent any particle. I will edit my post to provide some more context.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, I see. Yes, I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to be handling negative factorials in my question. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Solveig: cool, in that case you definitely do not need to compute the sum you wrote down to do this problem, and in particular there should definitely not be any negative factorials.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sum (lower or upper) of the series for $e^x$ is related to the [Regularized Incomplete Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/06/01/05/01/02/)
$$
Q\left( {n,z} \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \le n \in Z} \right.\;\;
 = {{\Gamma \left( {n,z} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( n \right)}}\quad
  = e^{\,\, - z} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {{{z^{\,k} } \over {k!\,}}} 
$$

Coming to your problem, we have
$$
P(n\;\left| N \right.) = \left( \matrix{  N \cr   n \cr}  \right)
\eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\,N - n} 
$$
which is clearly the probability of $n$ successes in $N$ trials.

We assume $N$ to follow a Poisson distribution with average $\overline N $
$$
P(N) = e^{\, - \,\overline N } {{\overline N ^{\,N} } \over {N!}}
$$
Now we have
$$
P(n\;\left| N \right.) = {{P\left( {n \wedge N} \right)} \over {P(N)}}
$$
and as rightly hinted in the text, for $P(n)$ we will have
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(n) = \sum\limits_{N = 0}^\infty  {P\left( {n \wedge N} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{N = 0}^\infty  {P(n\;\left| N \right.)P(N)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{N = 0}^\infty
  {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   n \cr}  \right)\eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\,N - n}
 e^{\, - \,\overline N } {{\overline N ^{\,N} } \over {N!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\, - n} e^{\, - \,\overline N }
 \sum\limits_{N = 0}^\infty  {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   n \cr}  \right)
{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N} } \over {N!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\, - n} e^{\, - \,\overline N }
 \sum\limits_{N = n}^\infty  {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   n \cr}  \right)
{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N} } \over {N!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\, - n} e^{\, - \,\overline N } } \over {n!}}
\sum\limits_{N = n}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N} }
 \over {\left( {N - n} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\, - n} e^{\, - \,\overline N } } \over {n!}}
\sum\limits_{N - n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N - n + n} }
 \over {\left( {N - n} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\eta ^{\,n} \left( {1 - \eta } \right)^{\, - n}
 \left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,n} } \over {n!}}e^{\, - \,\overline N }
 \sum\limits_{N - n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N - n} }
 \over {\left( {N - n} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {\eta \overline N } \right)^{\,n} } \over {n!}}e^{\, - \,\overline N }
 \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^k } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {\eta \overline N } \right)^{\,n} } \over {n!}}e^{\, - \,\overline N }
 e^{\,\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {\eta \overline N } \right)^{\,n} } \over {n!}}
e^{\, - \left( {\eta \,\overline N } \right)}  \cr} 
$$

That is, the key passage you got astray is at
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{N = n}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N} }
 \over {\left( {N - n} \right)!}}} \; \Rightarrow
 \sum\limits_{N - n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,N - n + n} }
 \over {\left( {N - n} \right)!}}}  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,n}
 \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty 
 {{{\left( {\overline N \left( {1 - \eta } \right)} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  \cr} 
$$
But it is good in any case that you learned about the occurring of $Q$ !

Comment: Thanks! Regularized Incomplete Gamma functions sound pretty neat and I look forward to learning about them in the future. However, I'm not yet at that level so I'm pretty sure I might have come up with the wrong equation to simplify.

Comment: Well there is no other close expression for it: note in fact that $Q$ expresses the Cumulative distribution of a random variable following the gamma and the Poisson (limit of the binomial) distributions, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables)

Comment: @G Cab I'm a little bit confused now. Are you saying that my expression was right? because I was indeed trying to express the probability distribution of a random variable following a poisson distribution when I came up with that equation (part b)). Yet I know that my teacher doesn't expect me to know anything about gamma fuctions. Or am I approaching part b) the wrong way and there is a way to answer it without knowing anything about gamma functions?